# Anyone have idea about the function of following code? (Haskell)

Tags: function, haskell, case

Anyone have idea about the function of the following codes?
here is the code:

```
data Cases a = Case_A | Case_B | Case_C | Case_D

test_list :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Cases a
test_list list_left list_right = case (list_left, list_right) of
  ([], []) -> Case_A
  ([], _) -> Case_B
  (_, []) -> Case_C
  (x:xs, y:ys)
       | (x==y) -> test_list xs ys
       | otherwise -> Case_D (x, y)
```

Who likes to tell me what is the function of it? Thanks XD

Comment: The code *doesn't* function as it doesn't look like it will type-check. In any case this question is too localized, and not a good fit here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this type for `Case`:

```
data Cases a = Case_A | Case_B | Case_C | Case_D (a, a)
```

The four cases mean:

- `Case_A`: The two lists were equal
- `Case_B`: The first list is a prefix of the second list
- `Case_C`: The second list is a prefix of the first list
- `Case_D`: The two lists have an element mismatch and it returns the elements which did not match.